# loop that checks every char in a string

Tags: c#, string

I'm making a cool thing that makes a secret letter that you can send to a friend, but I'm having a few problems.  I'm trying to make a for loop over every char in the string string, so it can check if the letter is a certain value and then change it.

This is my code :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string translatedtex = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();      
        int indexletter = translatedtex.Length;
            for (int item = 0; item < indexletter; item++)
            {
                char normal_a = 'a';    
              //   if(translatetext[item] = normal_a)
             //   { //do something 
            //    }

                if(translatetext[item] = "a")
                { //do something 

                }
            }
     }
```

I've tried switch the check of value between quotes `""` to `''` or `=` to `==` and nothing helps.
It always shows this error :
- property or indexer string.this[int] cannot be assigned to -- its read only 
- cannot implicitly convert type char to bool / string

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to do :D

But the syntax is correct now

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string translatedtext = richTextBox1.Text.ToString();      
        int indexletter = translatedtext.Length;
            for (int item = 0; item < indexletter; item++)
            {
                char normal_a = 'a';    
              //   if(translatedtext[item] == normal_a)
             //   { //do something 
            //    }

                if(translatedtext[item] == 'a')
                { //do something 

                }
            }
     }
```

And for your general knowledge:

"==" is used for comparison; "=" is used for assigning a value

"a" is used for strings; 'a' is used for chars

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` it saves you time and code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string translatedtext = richTextBox1.Text;//Text property is already a string 
                                             //no need to add ToString()

    foreach(char character in translatedtext)
    {
        if(character == 'a')
        {
            //Do something with character
        }

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There were two things I found wrong with your code. The reason you got the error is because you were using '=' instead of '==' in your if statement.  The second thing wrong is the redundancies.  You dont need to use ToString() on the textbox because it is already a string.  You can also use a foreach loop instead of a for since a string can be implicitly converted into a character array.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string translatedtext = richTextBox1.Text;                                         
    foreach(char character in translatedtext)
    {
        // '==' is used for comparison, '=' is used to assign
        // make sure you use '==' to compare in if statements
        if(character == 'a')
        {

        }
    }
 }
```